# Read one instance of Firebase DB - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Real Time Database that looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to read the `value` attribute of `Balance`, but I am not getting any response when I run this code in Swift:

```
 var userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
 var ref = Database.database().reference()

 func observeDB() {
 ref.child(userID!).child("Balance").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        print(userDict["value"] as! String)
    })
}
```

Is there another way that I can solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems simpler to me:

```
ref.child(userID!).child("Balance/value").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.value)
})
```

Differences with your code:

1. This listens directly to the `value` child of `Balance`.
2. This uses a listener on the `.value` event.

Both seems more direct translations of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I ended up getting nil, but that's because of another awkward error that I got. For some reason, the user ID in the database is different than the user ID in the authentication section, which I have to figure out. That's probably why I'm getting nil.

Comment: That would definitely *also* be a problem. But the combination `.childAdded` and the dictionary lookup certainly was also an issue.

Comment: @zander just a tip, always use authentication ID.